# Need to keep countertop, but fill hole where sink was

Tags: countertops

I took out a bathroom sink, but I don't want to replace the counter top. How can I fill the space?  It is Corian with a large oval hole.

I planned on securing something from the bottom. Should that be wood? Does anyone make anything like a drop in piece for it?  Suggestions?

Comment: I think you will need to make it or have someone make it.  I would not try to match it, but use it as a accent piece.  Maybe some nice wood or or something.  Will need some 1x3s under it for support.  The most important is the cut measurements of what you decide to put in the hole.

Comment: Some pics would help.

Comment: A cutting board in a bathroom, @keshlam? I don't want to know what you do in your bathrooms... o_0

Comment: Misread, sorry. Then again, removing a sink in a bathroom when one isn't redoing the whole cabinet?

Comment: How large is the counter top? Where will the new lavatory be? If the new one will be in a different place in the corian, could you use the cutout for that as most of the filler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Epoxy resin.  Infused with something you think looks nice.  Tint, glitter, bits of wood, marbles, flowers, you name it.  Look up "epoxy resin projects" on youtube for creative ideas.  Glue a board to the bottom of the counter and fill it with resin.  For irony you could tint it to make it look like a sink full of water.
2. Soil.  Seal it underneath using a vinyl board and silicone.  Fill it with soil.  Grow something creative.  Daffodils, wheat grass, IDK it's oval you could  make it a mini cricket pitch with real grass and little Lego players.
3. A black-hole-style parabolic coin roller, like they often have in museum lobbies.
4. A diorama of your favorite stadium.  Maybe [Wembley](https://www.nationalfootballmuseum.com/collections_detail/wembley-stadium-model-2003/) or [New Wembley](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/789115165931326308/) or one that has its place [in a bathroom](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=vagina%20stadium).

Comment: Good ideas.  They even get rid of the needed good cutting of wood to match the hole so the edges look good.

Comment: You can't grow things in a sealed container. The roots will rot and the soil will get rancid. (I assume that's a tongue-in-cheek suggestion along with #3, but....)

Comment: I for sure do not have a green thumb, and hopefully OP will think through the implementation issues before attempting any of my suggestions.   I guess for #2 you use train-set diorama style hobby materials instead of actual soil, but I know people who can make anything grow anywhere.  That's not legal advice. :)

Comment: I'm way over my head here but pretty sure bonsai pots don't have drains.  If I'm wrong please be gentle.

Comment: https://www.bonsaiempire.com/forum/repotting-and-soil/10272-purpose-of-a-pot-without-drainage-holes